# MySQL selecting time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `away` with the following fields

```
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| Name          |  from           |   to          |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| Lee           |  12-09-11       |   16-09-11    |
|               |                 |               |
| Mike          |  10-10-11       |   12-11-11    |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

What I need is a query to check if a person is away on a given day. For example `Lee` would be away on the 14-09-11 so I don't want to return this row.

Answer (score 2):

```
set @away:='2011-09-14';

select name 
from away
where `from`>@away and `to`<@away;
-- to encourage optimization
-- an index should be build on `from` and `to`
```

other problem - avoid using reserved keyword in table schema, it just **bad**

Comment: that is just an example of the table, I've had to change the names of the table and columns because its a secret project and can't give anything away

Comment: just the column name does not reveal what project you are really doing

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM away WHERE '14-09-11' NOT BETWEEN from AND to
```